# Как на Python создать эксель-файл с форматированием

Tags: python, база-данных, pandas, excel

У меня есть таблица в базе данных и небольшой графический интерфейс, чтобы пользователь мог работать с данными из этой таблицы. Хотелось бы добавить в этот интерфейс кнопку "загрузить в эксель", по нажатию на которую создавался бы эксель-файл с заполненной таблицей из базы данных. Основная сложность - сделать файл с форматированием, то есть при создании эксель-файла в нем заранее должны стоять фильтры и сортировки у столбцов таблицы, а так же некоторые строки таблицы должны быть окрашены в определенный цвет (в зависимости от данных в БД). Я слышал, что Pandas работает с экселем, но никогда подобным не занимался. Возможно ли реализовать то, что я хочу с относительно небольшими затратами?

Comment: пробуйте, обращайтесь с конкретными вопросами. Если просто написать по вашему тз - это к фрилансерам

Comment: Вопрос был задан, ответ - возможно.

Comment: Выбор подхода может зависеть от используемой OS. Если это Windows, то качественнее и проще всего сделать форматирование, на мой взгляд, через [win32com.client](http://snakeproject.ru/rubric/article.php?art=python_win32com_client)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Возможно ли реализовать то, что я хочу с относительно небольшими затратами?*" -  да, возможно.

*Основная сложность - сделать файл с форматированием, то есть при создании эксель-файла в нем заранее должны стоять фильтры и сортировки у столбцов таблицы, а так же некоторые строки таблицы должны быть окрашены в определенный цвет (в зависимости от данных в БД).* -  openpyxl и XlsxWriter - это на сегодняшний день  самые популярные модули для работы с Excel, если выполнять надо те действия, которые вы описали.

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html